# Is there a way to exclude Vuetify's _typography.sass?

Tags: vuetify.js

I recently started using Vuetify and I am struggling with the class names conflict. the `.title` is the particular one, because before using Vuetify I already using `.title` in many places. Simply because the name is too generic. I have found a way to overwrite them but still not ideal because technicatlly you cannot use `.title` anywhere. It is annoying. I found the style file is from Vuetify's _typography.sacss: [file link](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/elements/_typography.sass#L42).

I am wonder if there is a way exlude this file via `vue.config.js`, or even possible to rename/remove the classes like `.title`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Using `postcss-prefix-selector`. the idea is from https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8530

install postcss-prefix-selector

```
$ npm install postcss-prefix-selector
```

In `vue.config.js`

```
const prefixer = require('postcss-prefix-selector');

module.exports = {
  css: {
    sourceMap: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      /* solving the problem Vuetify's built-in style .v-application .title and others causing conflicts
      *  with existing title classes. */
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          prefixer({
            prefix: '',
            transform: function(prefix, selector, prefixedSelector) {
              if (selector.startsWith('.v-application')) {
                console.log(selector, prefixedSelector);
              }
              if (selector === '.v-application .title') {
                return `.v-application .v-title`;
              }
              else if (selector === '.v-application .headline') {
                return `.v-application .v-headline`;
              }
              else if (selector === '.v-application .caption') {
                return `.v-application .v-caption`;
              }
              else if (selector === '.v-application .overline') {
                return `.v-application .v-overline`;
              }
              else if (selector === '.v-application p') {
                return `.v-application .v-p`;
              }
              else {
                return prefixedSelector;
              }
            }
          })
        ]
      }

    },
  },
};
```